# Is there a way to create comparison and commonality wordclouds in python (as in r)

Tags: python, text, nlp, data-visualization, word-cloud

i'm trying to compare 3 sets of documents using a wordcloud with python.
in R there is a simple comparison wordcloud which shows the common words (or weighted by tfidf) per category with different color in the same wordcloud.
also there is a commonality wordcloud that shows the most common words from all categories.

I didnt find a way to do that in python. the closest i got was Venn diagram but i couldn't make the word-sizes relate to the tfidf score.

is there a way to create those wordclouds in python?

Comment: _is there a way to create those wordclouds in python?_ Yes, I'm sure there is.

Comment: One possibility to create wordclouds is [this](http://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/) [package](https://pypi.org/project/wordcloud/).

Comment: Do you have a more precise description of the desired wordclouds? Did you try to adapt existing a wordcloud generator to your needs?

Comment: here is an example of comparison cloud in r: https://images.app.goo.gl/bKjDJzboeM6WEQ5DA       
It compares 2 categories in the same corpus based on tfidf scores of each category

Comment: I too am looking for a Python counterpart for Comparison Wordclouds in R. Were you able to find it?

Comment: No... Sorry. Looked everywhere